# Как в компоненте в файле class.php получить текущие параметры компонента arParams?

Tags: битрикс

Пробовал вот так

```
$this->arParams
```

Ничего не выводит

Нашёл вот это

```
$arComponentParameters = CComponentUtil::GetComponentProps($componentName, $arCurrentValues = array(), $templateProperties = array());
```

Но оно выводит вообще все параметры компонента, а мне нужен массив $arParams с текущими параметрами компонента, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так заработало

```
var_export($this->arParams);
```